# how to fix run time error 5 in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

```
If Trim(size1box.Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the size for item 1!", vbExclamation, "What's your size?"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(qty1box.Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter quantity for item 1!", vbExclamation, "How many?"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    itemList = qty1box.Value & "unit(s) of " & Left(item1box.Value, InStr(item1box.Value, "(") - 1) & _
        "size " & size1box.Value & vbCrLf

    If item2box.Value = "" Then

        ans = MsgBox(namebox.Value & " (S/N: " & idbox.Value & ")" & " is requesting the following:" & vbCrLf _
            & vbCrLf & itemList & vbCrLf _
            & "Proceed with submission?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm request?")
        If ans = vbNo Then Exit Sub

        saveRequest 1
        GoTo Outro
    Else
        If Trim(size2box.Value) = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter the size for item 2!", vbExclamation, "What's your size?"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Trim(qty2box.Value) = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter quantity for item 2!", vbExclamation, "How many?"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        itemList = itemList & qty2box.Value & " unit(s) of " & Left(item2box.Value, InStr(item2box.Value, "(") - 1) & _
        "size " & size2box.Value & vbCrLf

        If item3box.Value = "" Then

            ans = MsgBox(namebox.Value & " (S/N: " & idbox.Value & ")" & " is requesting the following:" & vbCrLf _
                & vbCrLf & itemList & vbCrLf _
                & "Proceed with submission?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm request?")
            If ans = vbNo Then Exit Sub

            saveRequest 1
            saveRequest 2
```

> Run-Time Error 5: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

the problem start with this line :

```
itemList = qty1box.Value & "unit(s) of " & Left(item1box.Value, InStr(item1box.Value, "(") - 1) & _
    "size " & size1box.Value & vbCrLf
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain a bit about what you are trying? what is `itemlist` ? Go through [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When there is no "(" in item1box.value, you pass -1 to `Left`.

Comment: can you give me your email so we can discuss more on there?? i really really need your help